# Longest orphaned chain

Tags: blockchain, orphaned-block

In the history of Monero, what was the longest chain of orphaned blocks?

Can I easily find the answer by inspecting the blockchain?

Answer (score 3):

Its dificult to tell what is the longest, I personaly believe that should be the one created on the 4 september 2014 attack at block 122051, that block is hardcoded on the code so the daemon never sync for the orphan blockchain...

Still, I believe that some botnets keep mining on old block versions, thats the reason why on the daemon some times show messages pointing that we are X blocks haead

At the momment I dont think any explorer show that chains